# Is possible to create correctly a dynamicly vector <vector<pair<int, int>>> name; without declare a size, and then add items?

Tags: c++, vector

I create a vector of vector of pair:

```
vector <vector<pair<int, int>> name;
```

Next I need to add value to my vector (using this command):

```
name[1].push_back(std::make_pair(2, 3));
```

but I get error message: out of bounds. I understand why, but I dont know is a possible to create this vector "name" dynamicly without declare size of vector? I cant declare size of vector like this:

```
vector <vector<pair<int, int>> name(5);
```

because I dont know, how many rows will be inside.

What are the possibilities to solve my problem?

I need it, to pixel segmentation from images and create list of segment, but I dont know how many segment will be from any images.

Comment: What is `temp`? And what's giving you the out of bounds message?

Comment: I'm sorry "temp" should be "name". I get message: vector subscript out of range.

Comment: You don't need to declare the size of the vector, it will dynamically grow as more elements are pushed. Just call `push_back()` on `name`.

Comment: Yes it wil, but in this situation: vector<pair<int, int>> name; when I have one more vector <vector<pair<int, int>>> name; the compilator crashed ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to get access and display the contents of your map called "name":

```
for (const auto & pair1 : name) {
    for (const auto & pair2 : pair1.second) {
        std::cout << "{" << pair2.first << ", " << pair2.second << "}, ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I would avoid to use same variable name in both loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to push back a vector to push back a pair into first:

```
name.push_back(vector<pair<int, int>>());
```

Then you can do `name[0].push_back(std::pair(2, 3));`

Comment: since C++11, `>>` is valid.

Comment: @Jarod42 that's a nice addition, I always hate having to add the space. Editted my answer to remove the part saying you need a space between >>

Comment: Jarod how do this? First declare vector<int> name; then name.push_back(vector<pair<int, int>>()); ??

Answer (score 1):

You may resize when needed:

```
int index = 1;
name.resize(std::max(name.size(), index + 1u);
name[index].push_back(std::make_pair(2, 3));
```

if your index may be sparse, `std::map<int, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>>` may be an alternative, and you may directly do:

```
name[index].push_back(std::make_pair(2, 3));
```

Comment: This 2 method (alternative) how it works? "std::map<int, std::pair<int, int>>" where I should add a "name"? "std::map<int, std::pair<int, int>> name"?

Comment: Ok It's correct: map<int, pair<int, int>> name; but this line: name[index].push_back(std::make_pair(2, 3)); not working, is special command to add value to "map"?

Comment: Super, it's works :) Is a simple way to display value from "name"?

Comment: Something like `for (const auto& p : name) { std::cout << "index =" << p.first << std::endl; print_vector(p.second); }` with `map`. Its `iterator` once dereferenced is a (reference to) `std::pair<const Key, Value>`